# @PostConstruct method is not called in Spring

Tags: spring

SampleBean:

```
package com.springexample;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

public class SampleBean {

    private BeanTypeOne beanOne;

    private BeanTypeTwo beanTwo;

    public void init() {

        System.out.println("This is from the init() method");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initAnnotation() {

        System.out.println("This is from the initAnnotation() method");

    }
```

and config file like this :

```
<bean id="SampleBean" class="com.springexample.SampleBean">
    <property name="beanOne" ref="beanOneOne"></property>
    <property name="beanTwo" ref="beanTwoOne"></property>
</bean>
```

And I don't have ***default-init-method*** attribute set on the ***beans*** tag.

Can any body tell why the @PostConstruct method does not get called.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need `<context:annotation-config/>` (or `<context:component-scan/>`) to enable `@PostConstruct` handling.

Comment: yes it is working now..

Ya..I remember some time back i learned that..we need to have those elements to identify annotations..