# Spring @PostConstruct vs. init-method attribute

Tags: spring

Is there any difference between using the `@PostConstruct` annotation and declaring the same method as `init-method` in Spring XML configuration?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

No practically I don't think there is any difference but there are priorities in the way they work. `@PostConstruct`, `init-method` are BeanPostProcessors.

1. `@PostConstruct` is a JSR-250 annotation while `init-method` is Spring's way of having an initializing method.
2. If you have a `@PostConstruct` method, this will be called first before the initializing methods are called.
3. If your bean implements InitializingBean and overrides `afterPropertiesSet` , first `@PostConstruct` is called, then the `afterPropertiesSet` and then `init-method`.

For more info you can check Spring's [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-combined-effects).

Before JSR 250 specs , usage of init-method in xml was preferred way , as it decouples java classes (beans) from any spring specific classes/annotations.So if you are building a library that does not need to be dependent on spring infrastructure beans then use of init-method was preferred.During creation method u can specify the method that needs to be called as initialization method.

Now with introduction of JSR 250 specs in Java EE and spring support of these annotations , dependency on spring framework has been reduced to a certain extent.

But i have to admit that addition of these things increase the readability of code.So there are pros and cons both approaches.

Comment: If a bean is using more than one of those methods and relying on the order of initialization, it's going to be horribly complex and unmaintainable.

Comment: @Donal Quite true . Was just providing info on how this works.

Comment: There is an important difference: You need to specifically configure Spring to process annotations to make @PostConstruct work : http://stackoverflow.com/q/3434377/134898

Comment: `@PostConstruct` is from the package `javax.annotation` - which is deprecated in java 9 and removed in java 11. So, to use it, you should add additional dependency now.

Answer (score 21):

There's no real difference. It's down to how you prefer to configure your system, and that's a matter of personal choice. Myself, I prefer to use `@PostConstruct` annotations for my own code (as the bean is only correctly configured after the method is called) and I use `init-method` when instantiating beans from non-Spring-aware libraries (can't apply annotations there, of course!) but I can totally understand people wanting to do it all one way or the other.

Answer (score 6):

@postconstruct is not part of the spring. It is part of javax package. Both are the same. using init-method we need to added in xml file.If you use @postconstruct adding in xml is not required. Check out the below  article .

http://answersz.com/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy/

Answer (score 6):

Full code here: https://github.com/wkaczurba/so8519187 (**spring-boot**)

**Using annotations:**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class MyComponent implements InitializingBean {

    @Value("${mycomponent.value:Magic}")
    public String value;

    public MyComponent() {
        log.info("MyComponent in constructor: [{}]", value); // (0) displays: Null
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        log.info("MyComponent in postConstruct: [{}]", value); // (1) displays: Magic
    }

    @Override // init-method; overrides InitializingBean.afterPropertiesSet()
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        log.info("MyComponent in afterPropertiesSet: [{}]", value);  // (2) displays: Magic
    }   

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy() {
        log.info("MyComponent in preDestroy: [{}]", value); // (3) displays: Magic
    }
}
```

Gets us:

> Refreshing org.springframework.context...
>
> **MyComponent in constructor: [null]**
>   **MyComponent in postConstruct: [Magic]**
>   **MyComponent in afterPropertiesSet: [Magic]**
>   ...
>   
>   Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
>   Started DemoApplication in 0.561 seconds (JVM running for 1.011)
>   Closing org.springframework.context... Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
>   
>   ...
>   **MyComponent in preDestroy: [Magic]**

Answer (score 5):

There **might be** difference between `@PostConstruct` and `init-method` because  `@PostConstruct` is handled in the `postProcessAfterInitialization` phase of bean initialization (`AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean()` method) by `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, while `init` method gets called after the completion of `postProcessBeforeInitialization` phase (and, for this matter, before the beginning of `postProcessAfterInitialization` phase).
**EDIT**:
So, the sequence is:
1) `postProcessBeforeInitialization` phase,
2) `init` method gets called,
3) `postProcessAfterInitialization` phase, which calls `@PostConstruct` method

(As a side note, a statement from the accepted answer

> @PostConstruct, init-method are BeanPostProcessors

is not quite correct: `@PostConstruct` is handled by a `BeanPostProcessor`, `init` method is not.)

There **will be** difference if some (potentially custom) `BeanPostProcessor`, which is configured with (`Ordered.getOrder()`) to be executed after `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, is doing something serious in its `postProcessBeforeInitialization` method.
There **is no** any difference with the default Spring configuration of `BeanPostProcessors` because all the `BeanPostProcessors` which are configured to be executed after `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, don't do anything in `postProcessBeforeInitialization` method.

In conclusion, the accepted answer and the similar are right ... in 99% of the cases, and this post is just to pay a tribute to a concept "devil is in the details"

Comment: Hi! This is confusing, if PostConstruct runs before init-method, how is it handled by the postProcessAfterInitialization if init method runs after postProcessBeforeInitialization and before postProcessAfterInitialization???

Comment: @Maxrunner, sorry for the confusion and many thanks for letting know! In fact, I never meant to say that PostConstruct runs before init-method. Anyway, I updated my answer with some clarifications

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in the below diagram of *Bean Creation Life-Cycle Callback*.

[image: Bean Creation Life-Cycle Callback]

**This 3 step happens in the Bean Creation Life-Cycle Callback:**

1. It is mentioned that `@PostConstruct` will be called.
2. If `InitializingBean` is implemented, then `afterPropertiesSet()` will be called.
3. If bean definition contains `init-method` or `@Bean(initmethod="..")` then it calls the init method.

This diagram is from *Pro Spring 5: An In-Depth Guide to the Spring Framework and Its Tools*