# Spring: Why is afterPropertiesSet of InitializingBean needed when we have also custom init() or @PostConstuct

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

Why is `afterPropertiesSet` of  `InitializingBean` needed when we have also custom `init()` 
`@Bean(initMethod = "init")` or `@PostConstuct` ?
What actions can I do with one and not do with the other ?
When should I use one and not the other.
All are callbacks triggered after all properties are autowired.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In general, if a bean implements `InitializingBean`, first `@PostConstruct` is called, then the `afterPropertiesSet` and then `init-method`.

[image: Spring bean lifecycle]

`@PostConstruct` is a `JSR-250` annotation while `init-method` and `InitializingBean` is Spring's tools for bean initialization.

**InitializingBean vs. init-method**

Choosing between Spring tools, `init-method` and `destroy-method` is the recommended approach because of no direct dependency to Spring Framework and we can create our own methods. `init-method` is a way of calling custom method independent of Spring, if you'll decide to go with some other framework, you can reuse this method.

**PostConstruct vs. Spring tools**

Spring documentation provides clear explanation about preferable ways of initialization:

> To interact with the container's management of the bean lifecycle, you
>   can implement the Spring `InitializingBean` and `DisposableBean`
>   interfaces. The container calls `afterPropertiesSet()` for the former
>   and `destroy()` for the latter to allow the bean to perform certain
>   actions upon initialization and destruction of your beans.
>
> The JSR-250 `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` annotations are generally
>   considered best practice for receiving lifecycle callbacks in a modern
>   Spring application. Using these annotations means that your beans are
>   not coupled to Spring specific interfaces.

Comment: Could you please clarify the difference between `afterPropertiesSet` and  `init-method`

Comment: @Alma Shvartz First of all, `afterPropertiesSet` called before `init-method` but making a tight coupling of a bean with Spring Framework. `init-method` is a custom method independent of Spring, if yo'll decide to go with something else, you can reuse the method.

Comment: @J-Alex, Very nice diagram, with a tiny inaccuracy: `@PostConstruct` is part of `postProcessBeforeInitialization` phase, not a separate action. The details are in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519187/spring-postconstruct-vs-init-method-attribute