# Spring Boot with Kotlin: init block vs @PostConstruct annotation

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

In a Spring Boot application written in Kotlin it is possible to use both the [init block](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors) or the [`@PostConstruct` JSR-250 lifecycle annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) to do something right after instantiation. What are the consequences of using one vs the other in a `@Component` ? Can there be any behavioral difference?

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519187/spring-postconstruct-vs-init-method-attribute).

Answer (score 3):

An init block is pure Kotlin and has nothing to do with Spring.

`@PostConstruct` is a way to initialize after the Bean has been created an all dependencies are injected.

So if you want to access injected beans, you MUST use `@PostConstruct`.

For all other cases, you can use the init block or a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

As you said:

> do something **right after** instantiation.

*init* block gets executed **during** the instantiation. Therefore, the postconstruct annotation would be the right way to go, no matter whether you have injected beans or not.