# Spring how to execute method

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, dependency-injection

I know this question is a duplicate of [Execute method on startup in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401489/execute-method-on-startup-in-spring). however I have tried the advice posted in the accepted answer for that question, and nothing has worked for me. As such, I suspect that although it is the same *question* being asked here, I strongly feel that the root cause is different and thus requires a different answer/solution.

I am trying to get Spring to create a bean at start up and immediately execute one of its methods.

My spring config (`heartbeat-config.xml`):

```
<beans (all the xmlns stuff here ommitted for brevity)>
    <bean id="heartbeat" class="org.me.heartbeat.Heartbeat"/>
</beans>
```

And `Heartbeat.java`:

```
public class Heartbeat
{
    @PostConstruct
    public void start()
    {
        System.out.println("I should see this message in the logs somewhere!!");
    }
}
```

And finally, my `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <!-- The display name of this web application -->
    <display-name>Heartbeat</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/heartbeat-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

When I run this in Tomcat I don't get any startup errors. Tomcat looks like its running healthy (as I can tell from the logs). I do not, however, see any output in the logs that should be generated by the `System.out` invocation in my `start()` method (Tomcat redirects all standard output to its log files).

Am I overlooking something here? Is there an obvious diagnosis I could be performing?

Comment: You need to tell us what happened when you tried the solution from the other question, else we don't know how to answer differently, and this would still be a duplicate.

Comment: Alternatively can you not execute this from a constructor?

Comment: Ahhh, the only change I made from the other question was adding the `@PostConstruct` annotation. Same results either way, hence the solution did not work for me whereas it did work for the other asker.

Comment: flurdy what would my other options be? Can you post an example? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure it's the solution, but the API doc of ContextLoader uses `WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`, and not `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`. No leading slash. Could you put some debugging in the Heartbeat constructor to see if it's instantiated or not (or even start tomcat in debug mode).

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3434449/706695 ?

Comment: Good suggestioned JB Nizet! Now we're getting somewhere. I put an output statement in the (added) constructor and saw it show up in the logs. I did not have to remove that leading slash (and actually, this web.xml is a near-clone of another one used in a perfectly-functioning WAR, so I know thats not the issue). Any ideas as to why I can instantiate the bean but not call its `start()` method?!?!

Comment: HRigger - where would I place that context element? Under the `<beans>` element or inside my Heartbeat bean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most simple way to do that is to forget about annotations and change your bean definition to:

```
<bean id="heartbeat" class="org.me.heartbeat.Heartbeat" init-method="start"/>
```

If you want annotations you need to declare the context namespace and put this int your applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Enable @PostConstruct, @PreDestroy and friends in Spring -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="heartbeat" class="org.me.heartbeat.Heartbeat"/>
</beans>
```

Note: check the namespaces, they are copypasted from the net.