# Initializing Webservice

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

I have created a jax-ws Webservice using netbeans and jboss 4.0.5.

I'm trying to load some files right after deployment.

I have read that I have to use the Annotation @PostConstruct with the method public void init().

The issue here is that I'm trying to print some String to test if its working, but it never get to that init function.

Can somebody give some advice?

Comment: Are you sure you deploy your WS as EJB3? Well, it should not be EJB, but AS should support JSR-181: [JBossWS](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/JAX-WS+User+Guide) [supports that](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBWS-195).

Comment: Hi, Thanks.
I have created the webservice via Netbeans(using jax-ws), also i have my jboss 4.0.5 with JBossWS.
The thing is that I have created a very simple webservice that has one method "init", with the @PostCOnstruct annotation and its purpose is to print "WS from init method".
I think Im not deploying as EJB3.
Can you give me more advice please.
Also would you like me to post the full code.
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps I have mislead you: these annotations is JSR-109. I know that [`@PostConstruct` can be handled by Spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434377) and in your case the relative functionality was implemented in [JBWS-2268](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBWS-2268).

Comment: I have Solved it.
I have just added 
<servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class> and <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class> to web.xml, also i have created the archive sun-jaxws.xml
Havin all that in order, now whenever I deploy the webservice, it runs the method with the @PostConstruct annotation
Heres the link http://tundidor.com/blog/?p=78
Sorry is in spanish

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a new class like this:

```
@WebListener
public class Init implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public final void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
         System.out.println("Printed only on deployment");
    }

    @Override
    public final void contextDestroyed(final ServletContextEvent sce) {

    }
}
```