# Spring roo Service auto wiring in entities is always null (Using JPA Repository with @RooJpaEntity)

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-roo, autowired

I've been looking for a way to call some method from a service, when my entity is saved.

My App was created using roo 1.2.4.RELEASE

I have a Balance Entity called SaldoCliente and a ClientAction Entity called AuxCliente.

I need to update a client balance every time a new ClientAction entity gets persisted.

This is my code:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaEntity(entityName = "AUX_CLIENTES")
public class AuxCliente {


    @Transient
    @Autowired
    static private SaldoClienteService saldoClienteService;


...


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() 
    {
        System.out.println("Initializing with dependency ["+ saldoClienteService + "]");
    }

    @PostPersist
    private void afectaSaldoCliente(/*Long idTrans, Cliente, Integer cargo, BigDecimal importe, Integer creditos*/) {
      if (saldoClienteService == null) {
          System.out.println("saldoClienteService FUE NULL");
      }
...
```

I don't know why saldoClienteService is always null.

(Note I don't want a `saldoClienteService` field saved in my DB, hence the @Transient annotation)

I've been searching for a solution without success. Many of the explanations say something like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434449/2796922) where says: `You need <context:annotation-config/> (or <context:component-scan/>) to enable @PostConstruct handling.`

And I do have `<context:component-scan>` in my applicationContext.xml (created by Roo).

The documentation says:

> By default, the Spring-provided @Component, @Repository, @Service, and @Controller stereotypes 
>   will be detected. Note: This tag implies the effects of the 'annotation-config' tag, activating 
>   @Required, @Autowired, @PostConstruct, @PreDestroy, @Resource, @PersistenceContext and 
>   @PersistenceUnit annotations in the component classes, which is usually desired for autodetected 
>   components (without external configuration).

And at least the `@Autowired` annotation works everywhere but there.

Does anybody have some pointers?

------------------ EDITED -----------------

First of all: I want to thank @Sotirios and @Ralph for taking the time to help me.

If I remove "static" from the field, it's the same. The injected fields are always null in my Entities. (See my comments in this question, I added that because of a "possible" solution).

I'm having trouble also with another class I need injected. I added this to the same class as before (AuxClientes):

```
@Transient
@Autowired
private ConfigUser configUser;
```

And configUser is always null, also.

This is the beginning of the other class, in case it matters.

```
@RooJavaBean(settersByDefault=false)
public class ConfigUser {
...
```

and ofcourse, in applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean class="com.i4b.adminctes.util.ConfigUser" id="appConfigUser" />
```

I'm successfully using configUser in constructors, services and repositories. But can’t use it in Entities.

If you think I should post any other part of my code, just let me know.

--------------- EDIT 2 ------------------

The same happens with all my entities.

--------------- EDIT 3.a ------------------

I changed the question title, for a better one. Before it was:

> Spring roo (service autowiring) Entity not calling @PostConstruct . (Using JPA Repository with @RooJpaEntity)

--------------- EDIT 3.b ------------------

I have just created a minimal test project.

```
// Spring Roo 1.2.4.RELEASE [rev 75337cf] log opened at 2013-11-13 11:36:27
project --topLevelPackage org.example --projectName TestAutowiredOnEntities --java 7 --packaging WAR
jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY 
entity jpa --class ~.domain.MyEntity --testAutomatically --activeRecord false
field string --fieldName text 
repository jpa --interface ~.repository.MyEntityRepository --entity ~.domain.MyEntity
service type --interface ~.service.MyEntityService --entity ~.domain.MyEntity
web mvc setup 
web mvc all --package org.example.web
```

Edited the service:

```
package org.example.service;

public class MyEntityServiceImpl implements MyEntityService {

    @Override
    public String testAutowire() {
        return "Some data";
    }
}
```

Edited the entity:

```
package org.example.domain;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.example.service.MyEntityService;
import org.example.service.MyEntityServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.RooJavaBean;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.jpa.entity.RooJpaEntity;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.tostring.RooToString;

@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaEntity
public class MyEntity {

    @Transient
    @Autowired
    MyEntityService myEntityService; 

    /**
     */
    private String text;

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        if (myEntityService == null) {
            System.out.println("myEntityService IS NULL");
        } else {
            String data=myEntityService.testAutowire();
            System.out.println("it works: " + data);
            this.text = data;
        }
    } 
}
```

And edited the create.jspx to hide the service field. otherwise it doesn't let you save.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:field="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields" xmlns:form="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <form:create id="fc_org_example_domain_MyEntity" modelAttribute="myEntity" path="/myentitys" render="${empty dependencies}" z="T0LoTr6PZAwfIQHkjOZMmPW7cO8=">
        <field:input field="myEntityService" id="c_org_example_domain_MyEntity_myEntityService" render="false" z="12sHnsW2dWYyuD+vDtbTve/jWuI="/>
        <field:input field="text" id="c_org_example_domain_MyEntity_text" z="jUCTnP7E3pYPcZcfGn1tyJ2VeFI="/>
    </form:create>
    <form:dependency dependencies="${dependencies}" id="d_org_example_domain_MyEntity" render="${not empty dependencies}" z="Un0bJ/PmWmczxoVTom9NowwIRWk="/>
</div>
```

Then executed the application and created a new "My Entity". Leaving the field empty, I preassed the save button.

The log shows:

```
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/testAutowiredOnEntities] is completed
nov 13, 2013 2:31:52 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache tldScanJar
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
myEntityService IS NULL
```

And the entity has an empty text field.

Just to be sure, I added @Component to "MyEntity" class:

```
...
@Component
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaEntity
public class MyEntity {
...
```

Nothing changed. The service is still null.

I really hope it helps someone more knowledgable than me to help me find a solution.

Thank you all.

In the mean time, I'll re-read the documentation section @Ralph pointed out.
I'm obviously doing something wrong. I don't bielieve I'm the only one needing this.

Again: Thank you all

Comment: Spring can't autowire `static` fields like this.

Comment: oh... I added `static` because of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12241344): _"A hack to inject dependencies on stateless beans"_. But it didn't help

Comment: I'm getting desperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring does not inject in `static` fields.

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaEntity(entityName = "AUX_CLIENTES")
public class AuxCliente {


    @Transient
    @Autowired
    private SaldoClienteService saldoClienteService;

    @PostPersist
    void afectaSaldoCliente() {
       this.saldoClienteService.doWhatYouWant();
    }

}
```

---

regarding **update #2**

It looks like `ConfigUser` is an Hibernate/JPA/Whatever Entity but not an Spring Bean. But you can only inject Spring Beans (like Services, Dao, ... (Every thing that has an `@Component`, `@Controller`, `@Service`, `@Repository` annotation*.))

And you can only inject in Spring Beans or Classes annotated with `@Configurable` (requires AspectJ) [See Spring Reference Chapter 7.8.1 Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable)

Using `@Configurable` is the way Spring-Roo does (There must be a file `AuxCliente_Roo_Configurable.aj` next to your Entity (In Eclipse it needs to disable the "Hide generates Spring Roo ITDs"-Filter to display this file in the Package Explorer)).

---

** There are some more Ways that an object become a spring bean, but this does not matter here*

Comment: I updated my question. I get the same error with or without the field being "static". Any other ideas for me to try?

Comment: Wow... great response. Thank you so much. I have a question though. I'm not sure why the configUser @Autowired field is working fine on the services or other places. Do you know why?

Comment: Ok, thank you. About your comment about "update #2" I tried to add \@component to the ConfigUser and not in my Entity, in both and only in my Entity with no success. No matter what, configUser is always null in \@PrePersist. I even created e new roo project and it's the same. I will update my question

Comment: After all this time, I re-read the documentation and found that I didn't understand the @Configurable annotation. Don't know why I thought I couldn't use it in my case. To make the story short, just adding it to my entity class, made all the autowiring to get to work. At the end I decided to use a helper class to avoid all the Srping Roo created code for my "config" bean. I'll add a new answer to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working.

As I mentioned in my last comment to @Ralph: adding @Configurable annotation did the trick.

If the class looks like the following, the autowiring works:

```
@Configurable                <--- added this
@RooPlural("Tarjetas")
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaEntity
@Table(name = "TARJETAS")
public class Tarjeta {

    @Autowired
    @Transient
    private ConfigUser configUser;

...
```

**But** at the end I decided to use a helper class, in order to avoid all the Spring roo generated code for this attribute. I don't want to add a private getter for configUser in order to prevent the Spring Roo's public one to exist and mark 'render="false"' in all the scaffolded views.

Now I have:

```
@Configurable
@RooJavaBean
public class Helper {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigUser configUser;

    @Autowired
    private SaldoClienteService saldoClienteService;
}
```

When I need the autowired bean, I use something like this:

```
ConfigUser configUser = new Helper().getConfigUser();
```

Again: Thank you very much @Ralph