# Spring JPA Repositories @PostConstruct

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-orm

I am new to Spring (4.2.5) and JPA and I am facing issue related to @PostConstruct . In My project I wrote repositories and I am inserting data to them by using @PostConstruct and inside init method.

```
  @PostConstruct
  public void init(){
    Role roleUser = new Role();
    roleUser.setName("ROLE_USER");
    roleRepository.save(roleUser);

    Role roleAdmin = new Role();
    roleAdmin.setName("ROLE_ADMIN");
    roleRepository.save(roleAdmin);
}
```

I am initializing all repositories by calling  in applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.shiva.controller">
<context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
<context:annotation-config/>
 <jpa:repositories base-package="com.shiva.repository"  entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"  />
```

But in logs Tables are getting created but the problem is insert statement 
is not getting called and I might doubt that this init method is nit getting called.

These are the logs for table creation but I am not getting insert statements what I called from applicationContext.xml:

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists Blog
Hibernate: drop table if exists Item
Hibernate: drop table if exists Role
Hibernate: drop table if exists Role_User
Hibernate: drop table if exists User
Hibernate: drop table if exists User_Role
Hibernate: create table Blog (id integer not null auto_increment, name varchar(255), url varchar(255), user_id integer, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table Item (id integer not null auto_increment, description varchar(255), link varchar(255), published_date datetime, title varchar(255), blog_id integer, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table Role (id integer not null auto_increment, name varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table Role_User (Role_id integer not null, users_id integer not null)
Hibernate: create table User (id integer not null auto_increment, email varchar(255), name varchar(255), password varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table User_Role (User_id integer not null, roles_id integer not null)
```

How can I look into this issue?

Comment: Can you add a sysout in your postConstruct method and see if that method is even getting invoked or not?

Comment: I did syso in the method annotated with @postConstruct and it's not getting called :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks All for your response .... problem was in my **applicationServlet.xml**  file ... I modified the code to scan the jpaRepositories like this ..

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.shiva.repository"   entity-manager-factory-ref="emf" transaction-manager-ref="txManager" />
```

I gave the reference of entity-manager-factory and transaction-manager and it's working perfect for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Enable @PostConstruct  handling with:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Or

```
<context:component-scan/>
```

You can find here a similar post:

[@PostConstruct method is not called in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434377/postconstruct-method-is-not-called-in-spring)

Comment: my applicationContext.xml looks like this .... I already have <context:component-scan /> and <context:annotation-Config/>  .. but still  am facing the same issue ...                                        <context:component-scan base-package="com.shiva.controller">

<context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>

<context:annotation-config/>